# Can't set correct div width after populating it with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

This code populates an inner div inside an image slider, using an Ajax call :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: $(this).attr('href')
}).done(function (result) {
    
    // append thumbnails to lower slider
    var correct_width = 0;
    
    for (var $i = 0; $i < result[1].length; $i++) {
        $('#lower_slider').append("<img src='" + result[1][$i]['image_thumb_src'] + "'>");
        
        // calculate $('#lower_slider') width
        $('#lower_slider').find('img').each(function () {
            correct_width += $(this).outerWidth();
        });
    }
    
    // set $('#lower_slider') width
    $('#lower_slider').width(correct_width);
});
```

The functionality of this code works perfectly the second time it's executed - so obviously, it got to do with some race conditions. So how can I eliminate them?

p.s - I know this question has been asked for a different use, but none of the suggested solutions worked for me.

Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't be this code: $('#lower_slider').find('img').each(function () {
            correct_width += $(this).outerWidth();
        });  outside of "for (i..." loop?

Comment: Logic says yes, but when I tried it $('#lower_slider').width() was only of the first image to appear

Comment: also, you're missing "var" in the for lool: for (var $i = 0; $i < result[1].length; $i++) {

Comment: Thanks Ivan,I fixed it. still got the same problem though.

Comment: put that "each" segment after the loop (as logic says) and put this line: "console.log(correct_width);" before you set the width of #lower_slider - to see what's the end value

Comment: @Ivan, `correct_width` logged `75`, than only first image appeared, than it logged `75X10` (10 = result.length). this is when logging `correct_width` from within the `each`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68959/discussion-between-xroydot-and-ivan-sivak).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the second time it's working because the requested images are already cached.

Try calculating correct_width once the images have been loaded:

```
var correct_width = 0;
var imgArray = new Array();
var obj = this;

for (var $i = 0; $i < result[1].length; $i++) {
    imgArray[$i] = new Image();
    imgArray[$i].src = result[1][$i]['image_thumb_src'];
    imgArray[$i].onload = function() {
       $('#lower_slider').append("<img src='" + this.src + "'>");
       correct_width += $(obj).outerWidth();
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this code. But it should be ok.

Comment: I have added a line to the piece of code: "$('#lower_slider').append ..."

Comment: Thanks for the input, @estornes! something weird though, after applying your code i'm getting an error `Cannot read property 'image_thumb_src' of undefined`

Comment: it's this line : `$('#lower_slider').append("<img src='" + result[1][$i]['image_thumb_src'] + "'>");
`

Comment: Added a line: "imgArray[$i].index = $i;" and modified the buggy line

Comment: now the error is  - `Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined` which referred to this line :  `correct_width += $(obj).outerWidth();`

Comment: Is the width you must calculate the sum of the images' width?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68964/discussion-between-xroydot-and-estornes).

Answer (score 0):

Well, the only way I got it to work was by setting a delay before the resize and width calculation:

```
var correct_width = 0;

for (var $i = 0; $i < result[1].length; $i++) {
    $("#lower_slider").append(
        "<img src=" + result[1][$i]["image_thumb_srcand "] + "'>"
    );
}

var wait = setTimeout(function () {
    $("#lower_slider")
        .find("img")
        .each(function () {
            correct_width += $(this).outerWidth() + 10;
            $("#lower_slider").innerWidth(correct_width);
        });
}, 1000);
```

There might be better solutions but nothing else worked for me.